# Jabber Management on Linux

Tags: monitoring, configuration, xmpp

Does anyone know of a GUI for the configuration and management of a Jabber(2) server on Linux?
Shows logged-in users, allows you to ban/remove users, general configuration and monitoring?

Looking for recommendations from people who have used it!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Openfire server is an Jabber server that has a pretty slick GUI built in:

http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/index.jsp

I used this for over a year at a previous position and never had any interoperability issues with the common desktop clients or with iChat.

It's GPL licensed, though they have some other products (also Jabber based I believe) aimed at businesses.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [webmin](http://www.webmin.com/index.html).  They have a Jabber module.  I have never used it, but it is there.  Good luck, hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks RascalKing, will check it out. Not sure if webmin is overkill tho :)